# CentOS 7 VM (VMWare Fusion) IP Address not assigned to eth0

Tags: centos

I have a CentOS 7 VM (64 bit) running off a VMWare Fusion 8.5.10 on High Sierra. I recently moved the contents of an old mac-book to a new one.

I initially had some problems with ens33 being listed and no eth0 being found, which I resolved after make changes to my grub conf.

However, I never got an IP Address assigned to eth0. 
The contents of /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
#HWADDR=00:50:56:26:22:EE
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=eth0
DEVICE=eth0
#UUID=e82482f2-90e1-4c54-829f-a2c59931282e
ONBOOT=yes
#UUID=5fb06bd0-0bb0-7ffb-45f1-d6edd65f3e03
UUID=5fb06bd0-0bb0-7ffb-45f1-d6edd65f3e03
```

I have tried with 'HWADDR' uncommented but to no avail.

The command ifup eth0 fails with the error

```
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.
```

On my host system, I have a vmnet2 custom network configured.

It would be great if I can get this issue resolved. The VM was working perfectly fine on my old mac and the problem really started after moving the machine as part of the mac data migration.

Comment: Cheers for fixing the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Further probing around I found a nondescript mention of a similar issue and resolution at *https://www.techlanda.com/2016/08/error-no-suitable-device-found.html*.

Gist - the interface eth0 was declared as 'unmanaged by the Network Manager' and the VM rebooted. I could see an IP address getting assigned and I could access the internet from my VM. 
Having said that, I am still not sure why in the first place this was not working. I will endeavour to update this thread, if I find the answer. In the meantime, your suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: Added the line NM_CONTROLLED=no in the file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0